# Tool asks for a code to unlock and access the tool

Tags: assembly, reverse-engineering

```
.text:00CAB180 ; FUNCTION CHUNK AT .text:024AF380 SIZE 00000015 BYTES
.text:00CAB180
.text:00CAB180 ; __unwind { // SEH_CAB180
.text:00CAB180                 push    ebp
.text:00CAB181                 mov     ebp, esp
.text:00CAB183                 push    0FFFFFFFFh
.text:00CAB185                 push    offset SEH_CAB180
.text:00CAB18A                 mov     eax, large fs:0
.text:00CAB190                 push    eax
.text:00CAB191                 mov     large fs:0, esp
.text:00CAB198                 sub     esp, 350h
.text:00CAB19E                 mov     [ebp+var_80], 0
.text:00CAB1A5                 push    ecx
.text:00CAB1A6                 fld     ds:flt_2516A6C
.text:00CAB1AC                 fstp    [esp+360h+var_360]
.text:00CAB1AF                 push    0
.text:00CAB1B1                 push    offset aYouMustUnlockY ; "You must unlock your NaB version"
.text:00CAB1B6                 lea     ecx, [ebp+var_32C]
.text:00CAB1BC                 call    ??0NaB_dialog_name@@QAE@PADKM@Z ; NaB_dialog_name::NaB_dialog_name(char *,ulong,float)
.text:00CAB1C1 ;   try {
.text:00CAB1C1                 mov     [ebp+var_4], 0
.text:00CAB1C8                 mov     [ebp+var_7C], 32h ; '2'
.text:00CAB1CF                 mov     [ebp+var_F4], 0
.text:00CAB1D6                 lea     eax, [ebp+var_84]
.text:00CAB1DC                 push    eax
.text:00CAB1DD                 push    offset aBudabe   ; "Budabe"
.text:00CAB1E2                 push    80000001h
.text:00CAB1E7                 call    ds:RegOpenKeyA
.text:00CAB1ED                 lea     ecx, [ebp+var_7C]
.text:00CAB1F0                 push    ecx
.text:00CAB1F1                 lea     edx, [ebp+var_F4]
.text:00CAB1F7                 push    edx
.text:00CAB1F8                 push    offset aBudabeview ; "BudabeView"
.text:00CAB1FD                 mov     eax, [ebp+var_84]
.text:00CAB203                 push    eax
.text:00CAB204                 call    ds:RegQueryValueA
.text:00CAB20A                 mov     ecx, [ebp+var_84]
.text:00CAB210                 push    ecx
.text:00CAB211                 call    ds:RegCloseKey
.text:00CAB217                 lea     edx, [ebp+var_F4]
.text:00CAB21D                 mov     [ebp+var_340], edx
.text:00CAB223                 mov     eax, [ebp+var_340]
.text:00CAB229                 add     eax, 1
.text:00CAB22C                 mov     [ebp+var_344], eax
.text:00CAB232
.text:00CAB232 loc_CAB232:                             ; CODE XREF: sub_CAB180+CE?j
.text:00CAB232                 mov     ecx, [ebp+var_340]
.text:00CAB238                 mov     dl, [ecx]
.text:00CAB23A                 mov     [ebp+var_345], dl
.text:00CAB240                 add     [ebp+var_340], 1
.text:00CAB247                 cmp     [ebp+var_345], 0
.text:00CAB24E                 jnz     short loc_CAB232
.text:00CAB250                 mov     eax, [ebp+var_340]
.text:00CAB256                 sub     eax, [ebp+var_344]
.text:00CAB25C                 mov     [ebp+var_34C], eax
.text:00CAB262                 cmp     [ebp+var_34C], 10h
.text:00CAB269                 jnb     short loc_CAB271
.text:00CAB26B                 mov     [ebp+var_74], 0
.text:00CAB26F                 jmp     short loc_CAB2AF
.text:00CAB271 ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
.text:00CAB271
.text:00CAB271 loc_CAB271:                             ; CODE XREF: sub_CAB180+E9?j
.text:00CAB271                 mov     [ebp+var_78], 0
.text:00CAB278                 jmp     short loc_CAB283
.text:00CAB27A ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
.text:00CAB27A
.text:00CAB27A loc_CAB27A:                             ; CODE XREF: sub_CAB180+12D?j
.text:00CAB27A                 mov     ecx, [ebp+var_78]
.text:00CAB27D                 add     ecx, 2
.text:00CAB280                 mov     [ebp+var_78], ecx
.text:00CAB283
.text:00CAB283 loc_CAB283:                             ; CODE XREF: sub_CAB180+F8?j
.text:00CAB283                 cmp     [ebp+var_78], 10h
.text:00CAB287                 jge     short loc_CAB2AF
.text:00CAB289                 mov     edx, [ebp+var_78]
.text:00CAB28C                 movzx   ecx, [ebp+edx+var_F4]
.text:00CAB294                 mov     edx, [ebp+var_78]
.text:00CAB297                 movzx   eax, [ebp+edx+var_F3]
.text:00CAB29F                 add     ecx, eax
.text:00CAB2A1                 mov     eax, [ebp+var_78]
.text:00CAB2A4                 cdq
.text:00CAB2A5                 sub     eax, edx
.text:00CAB2A7                 sar     eax, 1
.text:00CAB2A9                 mov     [ebp+eax+var_74], cl
.text:00CAB2AD                 jmp     short loc_CAB27A
.text:00CAB2AF ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
.text:00CAB2AF
.text:00CAB2AF loc_CAB2AF:                             ; CODE XREF: sub_CAB180+EF?j
.text:00CAB2AF                                         ; sub_CAB180+107?j
.text:00CAB2AF                 mov     [ebp+var_6C], 0
.text:00CAB2B3                 mov     [ebp+var_88], 10h
.text:00CAB2BD                 lea     ecx, [ebp+var_88]
.text:00CAB2C3                 push    ecx
.text:00CAB2C4                 lea     edx, [ebp+var_1C3]
.text:00CAB2CA                 push    edx
.text:00CAB2CB                 call    ds:GetComputerNameA
.text:00CAB2D1                 mov     [ebp+var_1C4], 20h ; ' '
.text:00CAB2D8                 lea     eax, [ebp+var_1C4]
.text:00CAB2DE                 mov     [ebp+var_350], eax
.text:00CAB2E4                 mov     ecx, [ebp+var_350]
.text:00CAB2EA                 add     ecx, 1
.text:00CAB2ED                 mov     [ebp+var_354], ecx
.text:00CAB2F3
.text:00CAB2F3 loc_CAB2F3:                             ; CODE XREF: sub_CAB180+18F?j
.text:00CAB2F3                 mov     edx, [ebp+var_350]
.text:00CAB2F9                 mov     al, [edx]
.text:00CAB2FB                 mov     [ebp+var_355], al
.text:00CAB301                 add     [ebp+var_350], 1
.text:00CAB308                 cmp     [ebp+var_355], 0
.text:00CAB30F                 jnz     short loc_CAB2F3
.text:00CAB311                 mov     ecx, [ebp+var_350]
.text:00CAB317                 sub     ecx, [ebp+var_354]
.text:00CAB31D                 mov     [ebp+var_35C], ecx
.text:00CAB323                 lea     edx, [ebp+var_15C]
.text:00CAB329                 push    edx
.text:00CAB32A                 mov     eax, [ebp+var_35C]
.text:00CAB330                 push    eax
.text:00CAB331                 lea     ecx, [ebp+var_1C4]
.text:00CAB337                 push    ecx
.text:00CAB338                 call    sub_CA70C0
.text:00CAB33D                 add     esp, 0Ch
.text:00CAB340                 lea     edx, [ebp+var_74]
.text:00CAB343                 push    edx
.text:00CAB344                 lea     eax, [ebp+var_15C]
.text:00CAB34A                 push    eax
.text:00CAB34B                 call    ?STD_strcmp@@YAJPBD0@Z ; STD_strcmp(char const *,char const *)
.text:00CAB350                 add     esp, 8
.text:00CAB353                 test    eax, eax
.text:00CAB355                 jnz     short loc_CAB37E
.text:00CAB357                 mov     [ebp+var_330], 1
.text:00CAB357 ;   } // starts at CAB1C1
.text:00CAB361                 mov     [ebp+var_4], 0FFFFFFFFh
.text:00CAB368                 lea     ecx, [ebp+var_32C]
.text:00CAB36E                 call    ??1NaB_dialog_name@@UAE@XZ ; NaB_dialog_name::~NaB_dialog_name(void)
.text:00CAB373                 mov     eax, [ebp+var_330]
.text:00CAB379                 jmp     loc_CAB529
.text:00CAB37E ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
.text:00CAB37E
.text:00CAB37E loc_CAB37E:                             ; CODE XREF: sub_CAB180+1D5?j
.text:00CAB37E                                         ; sub_CAB180:loc_CAB435?j
.text:00CAB37E                 lea     ecx, [ebp+var_74]
.text:00CAB381                 push    ecx
.text:00CAB382                 lea     edx, [ebp+var_15C]
.text:00CAB388                 push    edx
.text:00CAB389                 call    ?STD_strcmp@@YAJPBD0@Z ; STD_strcmp(char const *,char const *)
.text:00CAB38E                 add     esp, 8
.text:00CAB391                 test    eax, eax
.text:00CAB393                 jz      loc_CAB43A
.text:00CAB399                 mov     eax, [ebp+var_80]
.text:00CAB39C                 add     eax, 1
.text:00CAB39F                 mov     [ebp+var_80], eax
.text:00CAB3A2                 lea     ecx, [ebp+var_32C]
.text:00CAB3A8                 call    ?DoModal@NaB_dialog@@UAEHXZ ; NaB_dialog::DoModal(void)
.text:00CAB3AD                 cmp     eax, 2
.text:00CAB3B0                 jnz     short loc_CAB3E3
.text:00CAB3B2                 mov     dword_2C69DA4, 0FFFFFFFFh
.text:00CAB3BC                 mov     [ebp+var_334], 0
.text:00CAB3C6                 mov     [ebp+var_4], 0FFFFFFFFh
.text:00CAB3CD                 lea     ecx, [ebp+var_32C]
.text:00CAB3D3                 call    ??1NaB_dialog_name@@UAE@XZ ; NaB_dialog_name::~NaB_dialog_name(void)
.text:00CAB3D8                 mov     eax, [ebp+var_334]
.text:00CAB3DE                 jmp     loc_CAB529
.text:00CAB3E3 ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
.text:00CAB3E3
.text:00CAB3E3 loc_CAB3E3:                             ; CODE XREF: sub_CAB180+230?j
.text:00CAB3E3                 push    32h ; '2'
.text:00CAB3E5                 lea     ecx, [ebp+var_234]
.text:00CAB3EB                 call    ds:mfc90d_1131
.text:00CAB3F1                 push    eax
.text:00CAB3F2                 lea     ecx, [ebp+var_74]
.text:00CAB3F5                 push    ecx
.text:00CAB3F6                 call    ?STD_strncpy@@YAXPADPBDK@Z ; STD_strncpy(char *,char const *,ulong)
.text:00CAB3FB                 add     esp, 0Ch
.text:00CAB3FE                 cmp     [ebp+var_80], 3
.text:00CAB402                 jnz     short loc_CAB435
.text:00CAB404                 mov     dword_2C69DA4, 0FFFFFFFFh
.text:00CAB40E                 mov     [ebp+var_338], 0
.text:00CAB418                 mov     [ebp+var_4], 0FFFFFFFFh
.text:00CAB41F                 lea     ecx, [ebp+var_32C]
.text:00CAB425                 call    ??1NaB_dialog_name@@UAE@XZ ; NaB_dialog_name::~NaB_dialog_name(void)
.text:00CAB42A                 mov     eax, [ebp+var_338]
.text:00CAB430                 jmp     loc_CAB529
.text:00CAB435 ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
.text:00CAB435
.text:00CAB435 loc_CAB435:                             ; CODE XREF: sub_CAB180+282?j
.text:00CAB435                 jmp     loc_CAB37E
.text:00CAB43A ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
.text:00CAB43A
.text:00CAB43A loc_CAB43A:                             ; CODE XREF: sub_CAB180+213?j
.text:00CAB43A                 mov     [ebp+var_78], 0
.text:00CAB441                 jmp     short loc_CAB44C
.text:00CAB443 ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
.text:00CAB443
.text:00CAB443 loc_CAB443:                             ; CODE XREF: sub_CAB180+32C?j
.text:00CAB443                 mov     edx, [ebp+var_78]
.text:00CAB446                 add     edx, 2
.text:00CAB449                 mov     [ebp+var_78], edx
.text:00CAB44C
.text:00CAB44C loc_CAB44C:                             ; CODE XREF: sub_CAB180+2C1?j
.text:00CAB44C                 cmp     [ebp+var_78], 10h
.text:00CAB450                 jge     short loc_CAB4AE
.text:00CAB452                 mov     eax, [ebp+var_78]
.text:00CAB455                 cdq
.text:00CAB456                 sub     eax, edx
.text:00CAB458                 sar     eax, 1
.text:00CAB45A                 movzx   eax, [ebp+eax+var_74]
.text:00CAB45F                 cdq
.text:00CAB460                 sub     eax, edx
.text:00CAB462                 sar     eax, 1
.text:00CAB464                 mov     ecx, [ebp+var_78]
.text:00CAB467                 mov     [ebp+ecx+var_F4], al
.text:00CAB46E                 mov     edx, [ebp+var_78]
.text:00CAB471                 movzx   eax, [ebp+edx+var_F4]
.text:00CAB479                 test    eax, eax
.text:00CAB47B                 jnz     short loc_CAB488
.text:00CAB47D                 mov     ecx, [ebp+var_78]
.text:00CAB480                 mov     [ebp+ecx+var_F4], 1
.text:00CAB488
.text:00CAB488 loc_CAB488:                             ; CODE XREF: sub_CAB180+2FB?j
.text:00CAB488                 mov     eax, [ebp+var_78]
.text:00CAB48B                 cdq
.text:00CAB48C                 sub     eax, edx
.text:00CAB48E                 sar     eax, 1
.text:00CAB490                 movzx   edx, [ebp+eax+var_74]
.text:00CAB495                 mov     eax, [ebp+var_78]
.text:00CAB498                 movzx   ecx, [ebp+eax+var_F4]
.text:00CAB4A0                 sub     edx, ecx
.text:00CAB4A2                 mov     eax, [ebp+var_78]
.text:00CAB4A5                 mov     [ebp+eax+var_F3], dl
.text:00CAB4AC                 jmp     short loc_CAB443
.text:00CAB4AE ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
.text:00CAB4AE
.text:00CAB4AE loc_CAB4AE:                             ; CODE XREF: sub_CAB180+2D0?j
.text:00CAB4AE                 mov     [ebp+var_E4], 0
.text:00CAB4B5                 lea     ecx, [ebp+var_84]
.text:00CAB4BB                 push    ecx
.text:00CAB4BC                 push    offset aBudabe   ; "Budabe"
.text:00CAB4C1                 push    80000001h
.text:00CAB4C6                 call    ds:RegCreateKeyA
.text:00CAB4CC                 lea     edx, [ebp+var_F4]
.text:00CAB4D2                 push    edx
.text:00CAB4D3                 call    ?STD_strlen@@YAKPBD@Z ; STD_strlen(char const *)
.text:00CAB4D8                 add     esp, 4
.text:00CAB4DB                 add     eax, 1
.text:00CAB4DE                 push    eax
.text:00CAB4DF                 lea     eax, [ebp+var_F4]
.text:00CAB4E5                 push    eax
.text:00CAB4E6                 push    1
.text:00CAB4E8                 push    offset aBudabeview ; "BudabeView"
.text:00CAB4ED                 mov     ecx, [ebp+var_84]
.text:00CAB4F3                 push    ecx
.text:00CAB4F4                 call    ds:RegSetValueA
.text:00CAB4FA                 mov     edx, [ebp+var_84]
.text:00CAB500                 push    edx
.text:00CAB501                 call    ds:RegCloseKey
.text:00CAB507                 mov     [ebp+var_33C], 1
.text:00CAB511                 mov     [ebp+var_4], 0FFFFFFFFh
.text:00CAB518                 lea     ecx, [ebp+var_32C]
.text:00CAB51E                 call    ??1NaB_dialog_name@@UAE@XZ ; NaB_dialog_name::~NaB_dialog_name(void)
.text:00CAB523                 mov     eax, [ebp+var_33C]
.text:00CAB529
.text:00CAB529 loc_CAB529:                             ; CODE XREF: sub_CAB180+1F9?j
.text:00CAB529                                         ; sub_CAB180+25E?j ...
.text:00CAB529                 mov     ecx, [ebp+var_C]
.text:00CAB52C                 mov     large fs:0, ecx
.text:00CAB533                 mov     esp, ebp
.text:00CAB535                 pop     ebp
.text:00CAB536                 retn
.text:00CAB536 ; } // starts at CAB180
.text:00CAB536 sub_CAB180      endp
.text:00CAB536
```

```
int sub_CAB180()
{
  const char *v1; // eax
  unsigned int v2; // eax
  char v3[248]; // [esp+34h] [ebp-32Ch] BYREF
  char v4[112]; // [esp+12Ch] [ebp-234h] BYREF
  char v5; // [esp+19Ch] [ebp-1C4h] BYREF
  CHAR v6[103]; // [esp+19Dh] [ebp-1C3h] BYREF
  char v7[104]; // [esp+204h] [ebp-15Ch] BYREF
  CHAR v8; // [esp+26Ch] [ebp-F4h] BYREF
  char v9[107]; // [esp+26Dh] [ebp-F3h] BYREF
  DWORD v10; // [esp+2D8h] [ebp-88h] BYREF
  HKEY v11; // [esp+2DCh] [ebp-84h] BYREF
  int v12; // [esp+2E0h] [ebp-80h]
  LONG v13; // [esp+2E4h] [ebp-7Ch] BYREF
  int i; // [esp+2E8h] [ebp-78h]
  char v15[104]; // [esp+2ECh] [ebp-74h] BYREF
  int v16; // [esp+35Ch] [ebp-4h]

  v12 = 0;
  NaB_dialog_name::NaB_dialog_name((NaB_dialog_name *)v3, "You must unlock your NaB version", 0, 0.1);
  v16 = 0;
  v13 = 50;
  v8 = 0;
  RegOpenKeyA(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, "Budabe", &v11);
  RegQueryValueA(v11, "BudabeView", &v8, &v13);
  RegCloseKey(v11);
  if ( (unsigned int)(&v9[strlen(&v8)] - v9) >= 0x10 )
  {
    for ( i = 0; i < 16; i += 2 )
      v15[i / 2] = v9[i] + v9[i - 1];
  }
  else
  {
    v15[0] = 0;
  }
  v15[8] = 0;
  v10 = 16;
  GetComputerNameA(v6, &v10);
  v5 = 32;
  sub_CA70C0(&v5, &v6[strlen(&v5)] - v6, v7);
  if ( STD_strcmp(v7, v15) )
  {
    while ( STD_strcmp(v7, v15) )
    {
      ++v12;
      if ( NaB_dialog::DoModal((NaB_dialog *)v3) != 2 )
      {
        v1 = (const char *)mfc90d_1131(v4);
        STD_strncpy(v15, v1, 0x32u);
        if ( v12 != 3 )
          continue;
      }
      dword_2C69DA4 = -1;
      v16 = -1;
      NaB_dialog_name::~NaB_dialog_name((NaB_dialog_name *)v3);
      return 0;
    }
    for ( i = 0; i < 16; i += 2 )
    {
      v9[i - 1] = (unsigned __int8)v15[i / 2] / 2;
      if ( !v9[i - 1] )
        v9[i - 1] = 1;
      v9[i] = v15[i / 2] - v9[i - 1];
    }
    v9[15] = 0;
    RegCreateKeyA(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, "Budabe", &v11);
    v2 = STD_strlen(&v8);
    RegSetValueA(v11, "BudabeView", 1u, &v8, v2 + 1);
    RegCloseKey(v11);
    v16 = -1;
    NaB_dialog_name::~NaB_dialog_name((NaB_dialog_name *)v3);
    return 1;
  }
  else
  {
    v16 = -1;
    NaB_dialog_name::~NaB_dialog_name((NaB_dialog_name *)v3);
    return 1;
  }
}
```

This one tool asks to enter a code to unlock the tool and have access to it, and it's a tool from 2012 and I've spent hours on IDA trying to understand how to bypass it and yet I'm here. This tool is not public anywhere so please don't jump to conclusions that I'm pirating something. If you're smarth enough, you should understand from the pseudo code that this isn't something to pirate for.

Comment: Looks fairly trivial to patch out the `if ( STD_strcmp(v7, v15) )`... what is your issue?

Comment: I'm wondering if it's possible to remove that line and re-compile it again? I got the PDB file along and IDA seems to not let me recompile it… What else can I do?

Comment: Just patch the binary.

Comment: Also do you mean removing the `if ( STD_strcmp(v7, v15) )` statement completely? What should I patch it to?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to change return 0 to return 1?

Comment: You can replace the `call STD_strcmp` with a `jmp` to whichever side of the `if` you want.  (Or actually replace the `push eax` before it which pushed args).  So when it runs, it doesn't compare, it just always jumps to where you want execution to go.  That leaves a bunch of dead code that you just jump over, but that's fine.

Comment: Do you think making it jump to `loc_CAB4AE` would bypass it?

Comment: and what would I replace `push eax` with?